# Configure Apace for HTTP and HTTPS with redirect secured by lets encrypt

Tags: apache2, https, redirect, letsencrypt

While I have used Linux in the past I am not very knowledgeable with it.

I have installed Apace on Ubuntu Server. I created a virtual host with Apace. All of this went ok. I am able to pull up the website using HTTP on a computer on the same network. Where I am having trouble is getting the site to load with HTTPS. I will also want to enable HTTP redirect. I will be using lets encrypt to secure it.

Can anybody provide me with advice, tips, tricks and or links to assist me in setting this up?

Answer (score 0):

I had to run the command:

```
sudo a2enmod ssl
sudo certbot --apache
```

Comment: Some explanation of the commands would be helpful.